# Is there a way to make content assist in Eclipse (JDT) show up automatically after I type "new"?

Tags: eclipse, new-operator, eclipse-jdt, content-assist

Most of the time after typing "new" I press Ctrl-space to quickly choose the necessary class.  I want Eclipse to show the tooltip automatically, like VS+Resharper does.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you add a screen shot that illustrates your wish?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have any hesitation in typing a single whitespace, you can add the whitespace character to the list of characters that will trigger the content assist dialog. The default character is the dot (.) character, to which you can add other characters.

I haven't found a way to avoid specifying any trigger character, and still get the content assist dialog. So, with the whitespace character in the list, you have to type in `new` instead of just `new`, and you can get what you desire (or more than what you need, as the dialog pops up on every space entered).

[image: Configure Eclipse's Content Assist Trigger to include a white space]

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  Unfortunately, content assist opening after every space is too annoying for me.  For example, in the piece of code shown on my screenshot, it will be triggered after I type `ArrayList ` (before `list`).

Comment: You can set the delay to a higher value (say 500ms or even 1s), but you can't have both in the JDT editor, unfortunately. Also, switching off unwanted proposal types (from the Advanced child node under the Content Assist one in the tree) could, but not necessarily help.

Comment: Also, there is the other option of writing a custom completion processor, but I doubt you'd like that option of essentially writing your own plugin.

Comment: I'll experiment with delay, maybe that will do.  Writing the plugin is much too hard solution for me.